# How to create class from class canonical name in java?

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting

I have class canonical name like this **dev.ashish.mvc.beans.Employee**.
Using this how can i create Class **Employee** at runtime in order access data members and member functions of Employee.

At runtime i want create class using its canonical name. At times it can be any entity Employee,Customer,User etc.

I tried this :

```
Class entityClass = Class.forName("dev.ashish.mvc.beans.Employee");
```

the above code does return class if i do **entityClass.getName()** it does return me **dev.ashish.mvc.beans.Employee** but how can i access methods of **class Employee** .

If i use java reflection like below :

```
Field field [] =  entityClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

it returns me declared fields of **class java.lang.Class** instead of  **dev.ashish.mvc.beans.Employee**

How can i achieve this ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have your class in `entityClass`, so calling `entityClass.getClass()` will give you `java.lang.Class` and `entityClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` will indeed give you methods of `Class` not of your particular class.

You need:

```
Field field [] =  entityClass.getDeclaredFields();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you did:

```
Class entityClass = Class.forName("dev.ashish.mvc.beans.Employee");
```

you just got class of Employee. Now you have to create instance of it:

```
Employee employee = (Employee) entityClass.newInstance();
```

**Update:**

My answer is wrong. I though you need to work with methods of instance. But you need to access class methods.

Comment: Do you mean that the fields declared in the class must be accessed after creating an instance of that class? If yes, please edit your answer. It is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, i though there is needed to work with instance of class. But author need to access methods of class. My answer is wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method by name thus (adding to what has already said by others)

```
Method methodToCall = cls.getMethod("method_name");//cls is of type Class (e.g Employee.class)
methodToCall.invoke(obj, args);//obj is of type Employee in your case
```

Note that cls is of type Class and you already have to have an instance of the class that you want to call a method on. Note that even if you're calling a method without arguments you still have to pass a class instance (obj in this example), which means that the first argument is always a class instance.

Answer (score 0):

We can create class from canonical name using apache commons library as

```
Class entityClass = org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(canonicalName);
```